# Nginx file uploads, where did the files go?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to support file uploads. I'm using the method described [here](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module/issues/41#issuecomment-15650730). My `nginx.conf` looks like:

```
    location /upload {
        limit_except POST              { deny all; } 

        client_body_temp_path          /tmp;
        client_body_in_file_only       on;
        client_body_buffer_size        128K;
        client_max_body_size           20G;

        return 201 $request_body_file;
    }
```

The idea here is that by switching on `client_body_in_file_only`, each request gets saved directly to disk. Also the filename that it was saved to is then returned to the client.

I can upload files with cURL and see that they are getting transferred in their entirety:

```
$ curl -i -F "data=@test.PNG" http://server/upload > out.txt   
  % Total    % Received % Xferd Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 100 3053k    0     0  100 3053k      0  7874k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 7889k
```

The file is 3 MB, and sure enough 3 MB was transferred. The response is:

```
$ cat out.txt 
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: nginx/1.13.4
Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 04:21:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Notice that I didn't get back a filename in the response body. Then on the server there's nothing under `/tmp/`. Where did the uploaded file go?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using the [`ngx_echo`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module) module. The key is the [`echo_read_request_body`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo_read_request_body) directive, which as the name implies explicitly reads the request body.

Removing the line

```
return 201 $request_body_file;
```

And replacing it with

```
echo_read_request_body;
echo $request_body_file;
```

Did the trick!